GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "}"
Creating an application using various tech stake. first time using garphQl in my project.
I am getting this error and not know how to solve this error.  I have try various chatbot support, stack overflow response but nothing work.
error i am getting :
F:\mars\graph-based-insights\backend> npm run dev

> backend@1.0.0 dev
> ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only src/app.ts

[INFO] 14:57:14 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.2, typescript ver. 5.5.4)
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "}".
    at syntaxError (F:\mars\graph-based-insights\backend\node_modules\graphql\error\syntaxError.js:15:10)
    at Parser.expectToken (F:\mars\graph-based-insights\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1397:40)
    at Parser.parseName (F:\mars\graph-based-insights\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:108:24)
    at Parser.parseFieldDefinition (F:\mars\graph-based-insights\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:836:23) 
    at Parser.optionalMany (F:\mars\graph-based-insights\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1492:28)        
    at Parser.parseFieldsDefinition (F:\mars\graph-based-insights\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:822:17)
    at Parser.parseObjectTypeDefinition (F:\mars\graph-based-insights\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:794:25)
    at Parser.parseDefinition (F:\mars\graph-based-insights\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:172:23)      
    at Parser.many (F:\mars\graph-based-insights\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:1511:26)
    at Parser.parseDocument (F:\mars\graph-based-insights\backend\node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:122:25)        
[ERROR] 14:57:27 GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "}".

To solve this error,  I have try modify  my files
here i am sharing those files with you, in hope of someone helping me resolving this error.
schema.ts :
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

export const typeDefs = gql`
  type Company {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    description: String
    foundingDate: String
    headquarters: String
    ticker: String
    investors: [Investor!]
    keyPersonnel: [Person!]
    acquisitions: [Company!]
  }

  type Person {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    role: String
    bio: String
    company: Company
  }

  type Investor {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    type: String
    investments: [Company!]
  }

  type News {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    description: String
    url: String
    publishedAt: String
    source: String
    sentiment: Float
  }

  type StockData {
    symbol: String!
    price: Float!
    change: Float!
    changePercent: Float!
  }

  type Query {
    company(id: ID!): Company
    person(id: ID!): Person
    investor(id: ID!): Investor
    searchCompanies(query: String!): [Company!]
    searchPeople(query: String!): [Person!]
    searchInvestors(query: String!): [Investor!]
    getCompanyNews(companyId: ID!): [News!]
    getStockData(symbol: String!): StockData
  }

  type Mutation {
    # Add your mutations here if needed
  }
`;


and this is resolver.ts code :
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { alphaVantageService } from './services/alphaVantageService';
import { newsApiService } from './services/newsApiService';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    company: async (_: any, { id }: { id: string }) => {
      return prisma.company.findUnique({
        where: { id },
        include: { investors: true, keyPersonnel: true, acquisitions: true },
      });
    },
    person: async (_: any, { id }: { id: string }) => {
      return prisma.person.findUnique({
        where: { id },
        include: { employedAt  : true },
      });
    },    
    investor: async (_: any, { id }: { id: string }) => {
      return prisma.investor.findUnique({
        where: { id },
        include: { investments: true },
      });
    },
    searchCompanies: async (_: any, { query }: { query: string }) => {
      return prisma.company.findMany({
        where: {
          OR: [
            { name: { contains: query, mode: 'insensitive' } },
            { ticker: { contains: query, mode: 'insensitive' } },
          ],
        },
      });
    },
    searchPeople: async (_: any, { query }: { query: string }) => {
      return prisma.person.findMany({
        where: {
          name: { contains: query, mode: 'insensitive' },
        },
        include: {employedAt : true },
      });
    },
    searchInvestors: async (_: any, { query }: { query: string }) => {
      return prisma.investor.findMany({
        where: {
          name: { contains: query, mode: 'insensitive' },
        },
      });
    },
    getCompanyNews: async (_: any, { companyId }: { companyId: string }) => {
      const company = await prisma.company.findUnique({ where: { id: companyId } });
      if (!company) throw new Error('Company not found');
      return newsApiService.getCompanyNews(company.name);
    },
    getStockData: async (_: any, { symbol }: { symbol: string }) => {
      return alphaVantageService.getStockData(symbol);
    },
  },
  Company: {
    investors: (parent: any) => prisma.investor.findMany({ where: { investments: { some: { id: parent.id } } } }),
    keyPersonnel: (parent: any) => prisma.person.findMany({ where: { companyId: parent.id } }),
  acquisitions: (parent: any) => prisma.company.findMany({ where: { id: parent.id } }),
  },
  Person: {
    company: (parent: any) => prisma.company.findUnique({ where: { id: parent.companyId } }),
  },
  Investor: {
    investments: (parent: any) => prisma.company.findMany({ where: { investors: { some: { id: parent.id } } } }),
  },
};


and finally this is my app.ts code. my server is also not starting at port 2001.
import express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { typeDefs } from './schema';
import { resolvers } from './resolvers';
import companyRoutes from './routes/companyRoutes';
import personRoutes from './routes/personRoutes';
import investorRoutes from './routes/investorRoutes';
import stockRoutes from './routes/stockRoutes';
import newsRoutes from './routes/newsRoutes';


dotenv.config();

// Initialize Express app,  Prisma client
const app = express();
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
console.log('Starting server...');


// Middleware
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000', 
  credentials: true
}));
app.use(express.json());

// Health check route
app.get('/health', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ status: 'OK' });
});
console.log('Starting server...');


// API routes
app.use('/api/companies', companyRoutes);
app.use('/api/persons', personRoutes);
app.use('/api/investors', investorRoutes);
app.use('/api/stocks', stockRoutes);
app.use('/api/news', newsRoutes);

// GraphQL setup
async function startApolloServer() {
  console.log('TypeDefs:', typeDefs);
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: ({ req }) => ({
      prisma,
    }),
    
  });

  await server.start();
  console.log('Apollo Server started');


  server.applyMiddleware({ app : app as any , path: '/graphql' });
}

startApolloServer();

// Error handling middleware
app.use((err: Error, req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('TypeDefs:', typeDefs);

  console.log(`GraphQL endpoint: http://localhost:${PORT}/graphql`);
});

// Graceful shutdown
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('SIGTERM signal received: closing HTTP server');
  prisma.$disconnect();
  process.exit(0);
});

export { app, prisma };



GraphQL doesn't allow empty types - either remove the type Mutation at the end of your GraphQL schema, or add the mutations you need in there.

thanks buddy for your help. no AI chat application help me to resolve this error.
